# Running out of space after allocating only ~1400MB when free space beforehand was significantly greater

Tags: c, linux, memory, virtualbox

I wrote a C program using linked lists to completely fill up ram to see how the operating system i was using would handle it.

screenshot of program and resource manager:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkeJG.png

I was running kali linux in virtualbox, and the os was only using 700-ish MB so free space was close to 3 gigs... however the memory filled up after only allocating 1420MB in my program. code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct node
{
  char val;
  struct node *next;
} node_t; // 16 bytes according to sizeof()

node_t *create_node(node_t *current, char newval)
{
  node_t *head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  head->val = newval;
  head->next = current;
  return head;
}

int main(void)
{
  node_t *head = NULL;

  for ( int i = 0; i < 1099511627776; i++ ) //arbitrarily large number
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 65536; j++ ) //64*1024
    {
      head = create_node(head, 'a');
    }
    usleep(11111);
    printf("%dMB\n", i+1);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

64 nodes should be a kilobyte (16*64 = 1024) and 1024 KB should be an MB...
so why is my ram being filled after only ~1400MB worth of allocations?

Comment: And malloc reserve the flexibility to allocate some more, so don't expect the memory is fully used when you allocate small pieces too many times.

Comment: @user3528438 fixed, had to hand copy the code over from virtualbox bc i couldn't get shared clipboard or drag n drop to work

Comment: `node_t; // 16 bytes according to sizeof()` The malloc() overhead is probably in the same range, effectively doubling your memory consumption. -->> avoid many*small allocations.

Comment: wow why is there such a large overhead?

Comment: @joop 16 bytes overhead per allocation?!? That would be a really bad allocator. I know implementations that use the free space in order to store bookkeeping information (dlmalloc). Though perhaps something related to a hardened implementation?

Comment: @DanielJour: What if there is _no free space_? Wherevever the managment data is stored, it does exist, thus needs space. And 16 bytes sounds pretty ok for a 32 bits system.

Comment: Note: `i < 1099511627776` is always true with 32-bit `int`  --> infinite loop.

Comment: "wow why is there such a large (16)  overhead?" --> On a machine managing > 1GB for speed and efficient memory utilization, 16 bytes is not a large overhead.

Comment: @DanielJour when i tested it, it was true, 16 bytes overhead per 16 byte node

Comment: @chux why is it not?

Comment: Typical memory allocation uses separate ideas of _minimum allocation size_, _hardware alignment_ requirements, _performance alignment_ requirements, _overhead_ per allocation and allocation scheme employed.  To well address allocation needs, we need to determine these values.  Much more info about your system and the compiler settings are needed to detail why "16 is not".

Comment: if someone can write an answer with what joop and chux have said i think i can accept it, and i'd really like to upvote some of the comments if there's a way, but i don't see any upvote button

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance you are fragmenting the memory.

Considering that one memory page is significantly larger then 16 bytes, and you are allocating 16 bytes by 16 bytes , you might end up having memory pages of 2048 or 4096 bytes with solely 16 bytes used (or more, but never the full page) .

If you want a better memory benchmark allocate byte arrays in continuous space (also make sure to commit the memory by writing to it).

Comment: if i understand things right, the os gives memory to the process page by page, but shouldn't the process use up the page before having another one allocated to it? why wouldn't/doesn't it?

Comment: Actually the OS gives the process multiple pages at the time, don't know exactly the algorithm according to which these pages are given thou. When the process decides to allocate a small object (such as yours) it will choose from one of the available pages and store it into that page, together with some overhead . At a certain time of an allocation the process might decide that it needs more pages , and ask the OS to increase it's memory, and then this will fail. Make a quick experiment and make arithmetic difference between the pointers. You will notice that they're not 16 bytes apart.

Comment: but why does the process not first use up the space it's given before asking for more, so much so that the program takes nearly double what it should?